# Conditional merge/replacement in R

Tags: r, match, r-faq

I have two data frames:

```
df1
x1  x2
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

and

```
df2
x1  x2
2   zz
3   qq
```

I want to replace some of the values in df1$x2 with values in df2$x2 based on the conditional match between df1$x1 and df2$x2 to produce:

```
df1
x1  x2
1   a
2   zz
3   qq
4   d
```

Answer (score 28):

use `match()`, assuming values in df1 are unique.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=1:4,x2=letters[1:4],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(x1=2:3,x2=c("zz","qq"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df1$x2[match(df2$x1,df1$x1)] <- df2$x2
> df1
  x1 x2
1  1  a
2  2 zz
3  3 qq
4  4  d
```

If the values aren't unique, use :

```
for(id in 1:nrow(df2)){
  df1$x2[df1$x1 %in% df2$x1[id]] <- df2$x2[id]
}
```

Comment: Nice.  I wrote the match with reversed arguments and couldn't figure out why it was more complicated than I thought it should be.  I'll add my answer as well because it may help others to think about how the changing the order of arguments in match can make things easier or harder.

Comment: Thanks Joris. I was working with 'match' but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I have added a solution that will perform better in the case of non-unique values in df1.

Answer (score 8):

We can use {powerjoin}, and handle the conflicting columns with `coalesce_yx`

```
library(powerjoin)
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:4, x2 = letters[1:4], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = 2:3, x2 = c("zz", "qq"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

power_left_join(df1, df2, by = "x1", conflict = coalesce_yx)
#>   x1 x2
#> 1  1  a
#> 2  2 zz
#> 3  3 qq
#> 4  4  d
```

Answer (score 7):

The first part of Joris' answer is good, but in the case of non-unique values in `df1`, the row-wise for-loop will not scale well on large data.frames.

You could use a `data.table` "update join" to modify in place, which will be quite fast:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
df1[df2, on = .(x1), x2 := i.x2]
```

Or, assuming you don't care about maintaining row order, you could use SQL-inspired `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
union_all(
  inner_join( df1["x1"], df2 ), # x1 from df1 with matches in df2, x2 from df2
  anti_join(  df1, df2["x1"] )  # rows of df1 with no match in df2
) # %>% arrange(x1) # optional, won't maintain an arbitrary row order
```

Either of these will scale much better than the row-wise for-loop.

Comment: The data.table idiom is `df1[df2, on=.(x1), x2 := i.x2 ]` -- modifies in place ("replace some of the values in df1$x2" as the OP asked) and doesn't require setting keys. It's similar to an update join from SQL.

Comment: @Frank yep you beat me to it.

Comment: Ok. `df1[df2, x2 := df2[,x2]]` is not the same thing, fyi.

Comment: @Frank True, yours is faster

Comment: @Frank looks like Hadley [decided not](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1275) to implement update join in dplyr, which seems like a weakness in the package to me.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Hadley's reason for excluding them is pretty weak (saying he's sticking to pure SQL), since update joins exist in some flavors of SQL. It just comes down to the "grammar" he came up with not being flexible enough.

Comment: Another suggested edit: `bind_rows(semi_join(df2, df1, by="x1"), anti_join(df1, df2, by="x1"))` as maybe more idiomatic for dplyr.

Comment: FYI I wrote a package that supports update joins. For instance using function `safe_left_join` a `conflict` argument can be set to `"patch"` or to `dplyr::coalesce` depending on the desired effect. See an example in my answer here with another function (but with equivalent effect in this case).

Answer (score 5):

I see that Joris and Aaron have both chosen to build examples without factors. I can certainly understand that choice. For the reader with columns that are already factors there would also be to option of coercion to "character". There is a strategy that avoids that constraint and which also allows for the possibility that there may be indices in `df2` that are not in `df1` which I believe would invalidate Joris Meys' but not Aaron's solutions posted so far:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=1:4,x2=letters[1:4])
df2 <- data.frame(x1=c(2,3,5), x2=c("zz", "qq", "xx") )
```

It requires that the levels be expanded to include the intersection of both factor variables and then also the need to drop non-matching columns (= NA values) in match(df1$x1, df2$x1)

```
 df1$x2 <- factor(df1$x2 , levels=c(levels(df1$x2), levels(df2$x2)) )
 df1$x2[na.omit(match(df2$x1,df1$x1))] <- df2$x2[which(df2$x1 %in% df1$x1)]
 df1
#-----------
  x1 x2
1  1  a
2  2 zz
3  3 qq
4  4  d
```

(Note that recent versions of R do not have `stringsAsFactors` set to TRUE in the `data.frame` function defaults, unlike it was for most of the history of R.)

Comment: Nice.  Factors can be tricky and the advice to expand the levels is helpful.  You do end up with an unneeded level in `df1$x2` though (the `xx`).

Comment: If you want to remove what are now superfluous levels, then do this: `df1$x2 <- factor(df1$x2)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by matching the other way too but it's more complicated.  Joris's solution is better but I'm putting this here also as a reminder to think about which way you want to match.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=1:4, x2=letters[1:4], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(x1=2:3, x2=c("zz", "qq"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
swap <- df2$x2[match(df1$x1, df2$x1)]
ok <- !is.na(swap)
df1$x2[ok] <- swap[ok]

> df1
  x1 x2
1  1  a
2  2 zz
3  3 qq
4  4  d
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with `dplyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1,df2,by = c("x1" = "x1")) %>% 
  transmute(x1 = x1,x2 = coalesce(x2.y,x2.x))

  x1 x2
1  1  a
2  2 zz
3  3 qq
4  4  d
```

Answer (score 3):

new here, but using the following dplyr approach seems to work as well
similar but slightly different to one of the answers above

```
df3 <- anti_join(df1, df2, by = "x1")
df3 <- rbind(df3, df2)
df3
```

Answer (score 0):

As of dplyr 1.0.0 there is a function specifically for this:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(x1=1:4,x2=letters[1:4],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(x1=2:3,x2=c("zz","qq"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


rows_update(df1, df2, by = "x1")
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65254214/2738526