# rollapply for large data using sparklyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr, rollapply, performanceanalytics

I want to estimate rolling value-at-risk for a dataset of about 22.5 million observations, thus I want to use sparklyr for fast computation. Here is what I did (using a sample database):

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

data(managers)
data <- zerofill(managers)
data<-as.data.frame(data)
class(data)
data$date=row.names(data)
lmanagers<-melt(data, id.vars=c('date'))
```

Now I estimate VaR using dplyr and PerformanceAnalytics packages:

```
library(zoo) # for rollapply()
var <- lmanagers %>% group_by(variable) %>% arrange(variable,date) %>% 
  mutate(var=rollapply(value, 10,FUN=function(x) VaR(x, p=.95, method="modified",align = "right"), partial=T))
```

This works fine. Now I do this to make use of sparklyr:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
lmanagers_sp <- copy_to(sc,lmanagers)
src_tbls(sc)

var_sp <- lmanagers_sp %>% group_by(variable) %>% arrange(variable,date) %>% 
  mutate(var=rollapply(value, 10,FUN=function(x) VaR(x, p=.95, method="modified",align = "right"), partial=T)) %>% 
  collect
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Error: Unknown input type: pairlist
```

Can anyone please tell me where is the error and what is the correct code? Or any other solution to estimate rolling VaR faster is also appreciates.

Comment: you do realize that `data$date=row.names(data)` gives you a vector of `character`, not of `Date`?  What happens if you do `data$date <- as.Date(row.names(data))`

Answer (score 5):

For custom `dplyr` backends like `sparklyr`, `mutate` does not currently support arbitrary R functions defined in other packages; therefore, `rollapply()` is currently unsupported.

In order to calculate value-at-risk in `sparklyr`, one approach is to [extend sparklyr using Scala and R](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/extending-spark-using-sparklyr-and-r/) and follow an approach similar to: [Estimating Financial Risk with Apache Spark](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/07/estimating-financial-risk-with-apache-spark/).

Answer (score 0):

Let me break your question into two tasks:

- how to do a rolling self-join (i.e., `a.manager_id = b.manager_id and a.date < b.date and b.date <= a.date + 10`) with `sparklyr` interface
- how to use a custom function (i.e., `VaR`) with `sparklyr` interface

The first task **might** be possible with the `dplyr` verbs, which support a limited set of [Window functions, including `lead()` and `lag()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html#lead-and-lag).  You'd probably end up with something really ugly, along the lines of `(lag(return,1) + lag(return,2) + lag(return,3))/(3 - is.na(lag(return,1)) - is.na(lag(return,2)) - is.na(lag(return,3))` -- just a generic example. (Unfortunately conditional joins, e.g., date windows, are still [unsupported](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2240) in `dplyr`- this question seems to come up often, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6112260/2573061).)

It would be much easier just to write the first task in Direct Spark SQL (with conditional self-join described above) wrapped with `DBI::dbGetQuery()`.

The second task is a statistical one that can't be done simply using `dplyr` or direct SQL, and it has a library dependency that `sparklyr` won't support, so you need to use a Scala (or Python) [user-defined function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#applying-user-defined-function) (UDF) to calculate VaR, such as the one [already linked](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/07/estimating-financial-risk-with-apache-spark/) in the other answer.

**tl;dr** First task is doable via `sparklyr` (but using SQL, not `dplyr`).  Second task requires an outside UDF that you can then [`invoke()`](https://spark.rstudio.com/extensions.html#calling_spark_from_r) via `sparklyr`.