# Update/Replace Values in Dataframe with Tidyverse Join

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the most efficient way to update/replace NAs in main dataset with (correct) values in a lookup table? This is such a common operation! Similar questions do not seem to have tidy solutions.

Constraints: 
1) Please assume a large number of missing values and bigger lookup table than the example given. So case-wise replacement operations would be impractical (no `case_when`, `if_else`, etc.)

2)The lookup table does not have all values of main dataframe, only the replacement ones.

Tidyverse solution answer much preferred. Similar questions do not seem to have tidy solutions.

```
library(tidyverse)

### Main Dataframe ###
df1 <- tibble(
  state_abbrev = state.abb[1:10],
  state_name = c(state.name[1:5], rep(NA, 3), state.name[9:10]),
  value = sample(500:1200, 10, replace=TRUE)
)


#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    state_abbrev state_name value
#>    <chr>        <chr>      <int>
#>  1 AL           Alabama      551
#>  2 AK           Alaska       765
#>  3 AZ           Arizona      508
#>  4 AR           Arkansas     756
#>  5 CA           California   741
#>  6 CO           <NA>        1100
#>  7 CT           <NA>         719
#>  8 DE           <NA>         874
#>  9 FL           Florida      749
#> 10 GA           Georgia      580


### Lookup Dataframe ###
lookup_df <- tibble(
  state_abbrev = state.abb[6:8],
  state_name = state.name[6:8]
)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   state_abbrev state_name 
#>   <chr>        <chr>      
#> 1 CO           Colorado   
#> 2 CT           Connecticut
#> 3 DE           Delaware
```

Ideally, a left_join would have a replacement option for missing values. Alas...

```
left_join(df1, lookup_df)
#> Joining, by = c("state_abbrev", "state_name")
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    state_abbrev state_name value
#>    <chr>        <chr>      <int>
#>  1 AL           Alabama      551
#>  2 AK           Alaska       765
#>  3 AZ           Arizona      508
#>  4 AR           Arkansas     756
#>  5 CA           California   741
#>  6 CO           <NA>        1100
#>  7 CT           <NA>         719
#>  8 DE           <NA>         874
#>  9 FL           Florida      749
#> 10 GA           Georgia      580
```

```

Created on 2018-07-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: You could just create a full look-up table and do a merge (left join)?

Comment: If the lookup table is more than two columns, it's an update join, which doesn't exist in dplyr ([for now](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/183)). The basic functionality is built defined in `coalesce`, though, which can be applied programmatically if you don't want to specify lots of column names.

Comment: @Ronak: This question marked as duplicate, though link does not go to tidy solution.

Comment: @alistaire: your suggestion, I think? `left_join(df1, lookup_df, by = "state_abbrev") %>% mutate(merged.col = coalesce(df.merged$state_name.x, state_name.y) ) %>% select(state_abbrev, state_name= merged.col, value) `

Comment: More or less, yes. I wrote a blog post about it: https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/

Comment: @alistaire: get this into dplyr at once!

Comment: @Nettle did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35636674/3962914) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Picking up [Alistaire's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572462/update-replace-values-in-dataframe-with-tidyverse-join?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment90111289_51572462) and [Nettle's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572462/update-replace-values-in-dataframe-with-tidyverse-join?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment90115110_51572462) suggestions and transforming into a working solution

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(lookup_df, by = "state_abbrev") %>% 
  mutate(state_name = coalesce(state_name.x, state_name.y)) %>% 
  select(-state_name.x, -state_name.y)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 3
>    state_abbrev value state_name 
>    <chr>        <int> <chr>      
>  1 AL             671 Alabama    
>  2 AK             501 Alaska     
>  3 AZ            1030 Arizona    
>  4 AR             694 Arkansas   
>  5 CA             881 California 
>  6 CO             821 Colorado   
>  7 CT             742 Connecticut
>  8 DE             665 Delaware   
>  9 FL             948 Florida    
> 10 GA             790 Georgia
> ```

---

The OP has stated to prefer a "tidyverse" solution. However, *update joins* are already available with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[setDT(lookup_df), on = "state_abbrev", state_name := i.state_name]
df1
```

> ```
>     state_abbrev  state_name value
>  1:           AL     Alabama  1103
>  2:           AK      Alaska  1036
>  3:           AZ     Arizona   811
>  4:           AR    Arkansas   604
>  5:           CA  California   868
>  6:           CO    Colorado  1129
>  7:           CT Connecticut   819
>  8:           DE    Delaware  1194
>  9:           FL     Florida   888
> 10:           GA     Georgia   501
> ```

#### Benchmark

```
library(bench)
bm <- press(
  na_share = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9),
  n_row = length(state.abb) * 2 * c(1, 100, 10000),
  {
    n_na <- na_share * length(state.abb)
    set.seed(1)
    na_idx <- sample(length(state.abb), n_na)
    tmp <- data.table(state_abbrev = state.abb, state_name = state.name)
    lookup_df <-tmp[na_idx] 
    tmp[na_idx, state_name := NA]
    df0 <- as_tibble(tmp[sample(length(state.abb), n_row, TRUE)])
    mark(
      dplyr = {
        df1 <- copy(df0)
        df1 <- df1 %>% 
          left_join(lookup_df, by = "state_abbrev") %>% 
          mutate(state_name = coalesce(state_name.x, state_name.y)) %>% 
          select(-state_name.x, -state_name.y)
        df1
      },
      upd_join = {
        df1 <- copy(df0)
        setDT(df1)[setDT(lookup_df), on = "state_abbrev", state_name := i.state_name]
        df1
      }
    )
  }
)
ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

`data.table`'s upate join is always faster (note the log time scale).

As the *update join* modifies the data object, a fresh copy is used for each benchmark run.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a single line solution with `rows_update()`:

```
df1 %>% 
  rows_update(lookup_df, by = "state_abbrev")
```

Demo:

```
library(dplyr)

### Main Dataframe ###
df1 <- tibble(
  state_abbrev = state.abb[1:10],
  state_name = c(state.name[1:5], rep(NA, 3), state.name[9:10]),
  value = sample(500:1200, 10, replace=TRUE)
)

### Lookup Dataframe ###
lookup_df <- tibble(
  state_abbrev = state.abb[6:8],
  state_name = state.name[6:8]
)

df1 %>% 
  rows_update(lookup_df, by = "state_abbrev")
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    state_abbrev state_name  value
#>    <chr>        <chr>       <int>
#>  1 AL           Alabama       532
#>  2 AK           Alaska        640
#>  3 AZ           Arizona       521
#>  4 AR           Arkansas      523
#>  5 CA           California    970
#>  6 CO           Colorado      695
#>  7 CT           Connecticut   504
#>  8 DE           Delaware     1088
#>  9 FL           Florida       979
#> 10 GA           Georgia      1059
```

Comment: Love this! Worth noting that `rows_update()` doesn't work (yet, I hope!) if the key is duplicated (like multiple rows with state_abbrev "CO"). Not a problem with this data, but I've got to find another solution for my problem.

Answer (score 4):

There's currently no one-shot for trying to coalesce more than one column (which can be done by using [a lookup table approach](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#applications) within `ifelse(is.na(value), ..., value)`), though [there has been discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/183) of how such behavior may be implemented. For now, you can build it manually. If you've got a lot of columns, you can `coalesce` programmatically, or even [put it in a function](https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/).

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
    state_abbrev = state.abb[1:10],
    state_name = c(state.name[1:5], rep(NA, 3), state.name[9:10]),
    value = sample(500:1200, 10, replace=TRUE)
)

lookup_df <- tibble(
    state_abbrev = state.abb[6:8],
    state_name = state.name[6:8]
)

df1 %>% 
    full_join(lookup_df, by = 'state_abbrev') %>% 
    bind_cols(map_dfc(grep('.x', names(.), value = TRUE), function(x){
        set_names(
            list(coalesce(.[[x]], .[[gsub('.x', '.y', x)]])), 
            gsub('.x', '', x)
        )
    })) %>% 
    select(union(names(df1), names(lookup_df)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    state_abbrev state_name  value
#>    <chr>        <chr>       <int>
#>  1 AL           Alabama       877
#>  2 AK           Alaska       1048
#>  3 AZ           Arizona       973
#>  4 AR           Arkansas      860
#>  5 CA           California    938
#>  6 CO           Colorado      639
#>  7 CT           Connecticut   547
#>  8 DE           Delaware      672
#>  9 FL           Florida       667
#> 10 GA           Georgia      1142
```

Comment: Does the `coalesce` approach only work with `NA` and not other kinds of missingness like empty strings?

Comment: Correct. An empty string is data in R, like an integer value of 0. Convert them to NA with `na_if`, if you need.

Answer (score 1):

in order to preserve the column order:

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(lookup_df, by = "state_abbrev") %>% 
  mutate(state_name.x = coalesce(state_name.x, state_name.y)) %>% 
  rename(state_name = state_name.x) %>%
  select(-state_name.y)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the abbreviation column is complete and the lookup table is complete, could you just drop the state_name column and then join?

```
left_join(df1 %>% select(-state_name), lookup_df, by = 'state_abbrev') %>% 
  select(state_abbrev, state_name, value)
```

Another option could be to use `match` and `if_else` in a `mutate` call using the built in state name and abbreviation lists:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(state_name = if_else(is.na(state_name), state.name[match(state_abbrev,state.abb)], state_name))
```

Both give the same output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   state_abbrev state_name  value
   <chr>        <chr>       <int>
 1 AL           Alabama       525
 2 AK           Alaska        719
 3 AZ           Arizona      1186
 4 AR           Arkansas     1051
 5 CA           California    888
 6 CO           Colorado      615
 7 CT           Connecticut   578
 8 DE           Delaware      894
 9 FL           Florida       536
10 GA           Georgia       599
```