# Overwrite a specific value in a dataframe, based on matching values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My data is in a format like this:

```
#>   country year value
#> 1     AUS 2019   100
#> 2     USA 2019   120
#> 3     AUS 2018    90
```

```r
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
     country = c("AUS", "USA", "AUS"),
        year = c(2019, 2019, 2018),
       value = c(100, 120, 90)
)
```

and I have an one row dataframe that represents a revision that should overwrite the existing record in my data.

```
#>   country year value
#> 1     AUS 2019   500
```

```
df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  country = c("AUS"),
                     year = c(2018),
                    value = c(500)
             )
```

My desired output is:

```
#>   country year value
#> 1     AUS 2019   100
#> 2     USA 2019   120
#> 3     AUS 2018   500
```

I know how to find the row to overwrite:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% filter(country == overwrite$country & year == overwrite$year) %>% 
  mutate(value = overwrite$value)
```

but how do I put that back in the original dataframe?

Tidyverse answers are easier for me to work with, but I'm open to any solutions.

Comment: Relevant [blog post](https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/) from @alistaire. From the comments in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572462/update-replace-values-in-dataframe-with-tidyverse-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mutate` and `if_else`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
mutate(value = if_else(country %in% df2$country & year %in% df2$year, df2$value, value))
```

Results in:

```
country year value
1     AUS 2019   100
2     USA 2019   120
3     AUS 2018   500
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, an efficient approach is join `on` with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), join `on` with the 'df2' on 'country', 'year' assign (`:=`) the 'value' column from second dataset (`i.value`) to replace the 'value' in original dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df2, value := i.value, on = .(country, year)]
df
#    country year value
#1:     AUS 2019   100
#2:     USA 2019   120
#3:     AUS 2018   500
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible tidyverse approach using 1). `anti_join` to remove the rows from `df` that will be replaced and 2). `bind_rows` to add the replacement rows from `df2`:

```r
library(dplyr)

anti_join(df, df2, by = c("country", "year")) %>% bind_rows(df2)
#>   country year value
#> 1     AUS 2019   100
#> 2     USA 2019   120
#> 3     AUS 2018   500
```

---

Or, another one using 1). `right_join` to join the old and new values and 2). `coalesce` to keep only the new values:

```r
right_join(df2, df, by = c("country", "year")) %>%
    transmute(country, year, value = coalesce(value.x, value.y))
#>   country year value
#> 1     AUS 2019   100
#> 2     USA 2019   120
#> 3     AUS 2018   500
```