# Conditional merge/replacement in R: Do it progamatically

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

My question pertains to this post: [Conditional merge/replacement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112260/conditional-merge-replacement-in-r)

I am using the data.table solution referenced there. The only issue is that I need to do this as part of a loop. In essence, I just need the following code to work:

```
library(data.table)
df1 = data.table(x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), x2 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
df2 = data.table(x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x2 = c('a', 'x', 'x', 'd'))
z = df1[df2, on = .(x1), x2 := i.x2] # Works perfectly

varname = 'x2'
z = df1[df2, on = .(x1), get(varname) := i.get(varname)] # Doesn't work
```

Comment: You can do: `(varname) := get(sprintf("i.%s", varname))`
There is no need for get on the left side. For multiple variables, you can use `mget` as shown in the link.

Comment: I see. My mistake was using get on the RHS. Even `df1[df2, on = .(x1), (varname) := get(paste0('i.',varname))]` works.